# Laravel 8 & Livewire Events not working well

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i'm developing an application with laravel 8 and livewire.
I've created in the view `gestionale.blade.php` three component (table) with the following operation.

The first table is populated when the page is loaded, then a row is selected and the second table is populated with a click event, finally by clicking a row in the second table the third table is populated.
From the Livewire documentation I used the events, but I only have the correct functioning of the first one, that is, clicking on the first table populates the second, but then clicking a row on the second I get nothing.
I entered a dump & die inside the code and I just don't get to raise the event in the second table.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\MinutaArticolo;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Tenant;

class TableArticoliContent extends Component
{
    //Dichiariamo il listener degli eventi
    protected $listeners = ['getArticoli' => 'getArticoli'];
    protected $connection = null;
    public $articoli = null;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function mount(Request $request) {
        if(null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) 
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        else
            $this->connection = null; 
    }
    
    // Funzione richiamata dal componente livewire e che ritorna gli articoli
    // a seconda dell'id partita passato
    public function getArticoli($id_partita) {
        
        if(null !== request()->get('throughMiddleware')) 
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        else
            $this->connection = null; 

        $this->articoli = MinutaArticolo::on($this->connection)->where('id_minuta_partita', '=', $id_partita)->paginate(15)->toArray();
    }

    public function render()
    { 
        return view('livewire.table-articoli-content')
            ->with('articoli', $this->articoli);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\MinutaArticolo;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Tenant;

class TableArticoli extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';


    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.table-articoli');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AnagraficaSoggetto;

class TablePraticheContent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    protected $connection = null;
    public $pratiche = null;
    protected $listeners = ['filtri' => 'renderWithFilter'];

    public function mount(Request $request) {

        // Setto la connessione
        if(null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) 
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        else
            $this->connection = null; 

        // Recupero i dati da renderizzare 

        $anagrafica = new AnagraficaSoggetto();
        $anagrafica->setConnection($this->connection);

        $this->pratiche = $anagrafica->select(
            'denominazioneSoggetto',
            'anagrafica_soggetto.codiceFiscale',
            'indirizzoPOSTA',
            'tipologia_imposta.descrizione_sintetica',
            'importoCarico as carico',
            'importoResiduo as residuo',
            'pagatoNormale as riscosso',
            'pagatoDiscarico as sgravio',
            'data_assegnazione',
            'username as collaboratore',
            'minuta_partita.id',
            'minuta_partita.id_minuta as id_minuta',
            'partita_pagamenti.progressivoRiscossione',
            'partita_pagamenti.agenteRiscossione'
        )->distinct()
            ->join('minuta_partita', 'minuta_partita.id_soggetto', '=', 'anagrafica_soggetto.id')
            ->join('users', 'minuta_partita.id_user', '=', 'users.id', 'left outer')
            ->join('partita_pagamenti', 'partita_pagamenti.id_minuta_partita', '=', 'minuta_partita.id', 'left outer')
            ->join('tipologia_imposta', 'minuta_partita.id_tipologia_imposta', '=', 'tipologia_imposta.id')
            ->paginate(15)->toArray(); 
    }

    //funzione per triggerare l'evento onclick sulla tabella pratiche
    public function clickPartiteTrigger($id) {
        $this->emit('getPartite', $id);
        $this->render = false;
    }


    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.table-pratiche-content')
        ->with('pratiche', $this->pratiche);
    }

    public function renderWithFilter($filtered){
            $this->pratiche = $filtered;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\AnagraficaSoggetto;

class TablePratiche extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';


    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.table-pratiche');
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\MinutaPartita;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Tenant;

class TablePartiteContent extends Component
{
    //Dichiariamo il listener degli eventi
    protected $listeners = ['getPartite' => 'getPartite',
                            'filtri_partite' => 'renderWithFilter'];
    protected $connection = null;
    public $partite = null;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function mount(Request $request) {

        if(null !== $request->get('throughMiddleware')) 
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        else
            $this->connection = null; 

    }

    //funzione per triggerare l'evento onclick sulla tabella partite
    public function clickArticoliTrigger($id) {
        dd($id);
        $this->emit('getArticoli', $id);
        $this->render = false;
    }

    // Funzione richiamata dal componente livewire e che ritorna le partite
    // a seconda dell'id pratica passato
    public function getPartite($id_minuta) {

        if(null !== request()->get('throughMiddleware')) 
            $this->connection = 'tenant';
        else
            $this->connection = null; 
            
        $this->partite = MinutaPartita::on($this->connection)->where('id_minuta', '=', $id_minuta)->paginate(15)->toArray();
    }
    
    public function render() {    
        return view('livewire.table-partite-content')
            ->with('partite', $this->partite);
    }

    public function renderWithFilter($filtered){
        $this->partite = $filtered;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\MinutaPartita;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Tenant;

class TablePartite extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';


    public function render() {
        return view('livewire.table-partite');
    }
}
```

and this is my component in which i've the event which must make me populate the third table

```
<tbody id="partite_result">
                    @if (!empty($partite))
                    @foreach ($partite['data'] as $pt)
                    <tr wire:click="clickArticoliTrigger({{ $pt['id']}})">
                        <td>{{ $pt['annoRuolo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['numeroRuolo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['agenteRiscossione'] ?? ''}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['annoRif'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['tipoImposta'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['id_minuta_partita'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoCarico'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['pagatoNormale'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['pagatoDiscarico'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoResiduo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['proceduraEsecutiva'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoInesigibilita'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['stato'] ?? ''}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
</tbody>
```

Can someone have any tips or advice to help me? Thanks to all :-)

EDIT (this is my component code):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title">Partite</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="example5" class="display" style="min-width: 845px">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Anno ruolo</th>
                    <th>Numero ruolo</th>
                    <th>Agente Riscossione</th>
                    <th>Anno imposta</th>
                    <th>Tipo imposta</th>
                    <th>Partita</th>
                    <th>Carico</th>
                    <th>Riscosso</th>
                    <th>Sgravio</th>
                    <th>Residuo</th>
                    <th>Peocedura</th>
                    <th>Inesigibile</th>
                    <th>Stato</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <livewire:table-partite-content />
                <livewire:tbl-partite-footer-filter />
              </table>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that table content is inside div container in the blade?

Comment: Yes, this content is inside div container...i put my code editing my answer if you wont look

Comment: but in the first table, created in the same way as the code I posted for the component that does not work, the click event on the row works and populates the table whose code I posted and which does not take the click event

Comment: It's a bit confuse for me because don't get the order of the components, like who is parent and whose is nested components. Besides, the different views name on render method get me crazy, like table-partite-content and table-pratiche-content and I can figure out in this simple post. If you can, post here like a pseudo-code of the parent and nested component order and its blades names

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the code more clearly in the question below

Answer (score 0):

Clearer code:

I've this route: `Route::get('/gestionale', [App\Http\Controllers\GestionaleController::class, 'index']);`

And i go in the view blade called `gestionale.blade.php` and in this view i've my three livewire component.
The code of the view `gestionale.blade.php` is:

```
{{-- Extends layout --}}
@extends('layout.layout2')



{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row page-titles mx-0">
        <div class="col-sm-6 p-md-0">
            <div class="welcome-text">
                <h4>Benvenuto sul Gestionale</h4>
                <span>Qui sono listate pratche, partite e articoli</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- import del componente gestionale header filter per i filtri -->
    <livewire:gestionale-header-filter>
    <!-- fine import del componente gestionale header filter -->
  <hr/>
    <!-- import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
    <livewire:table-pratiche />  // first component (event on this works)
    <hr/>
    <livewire:table-partite /> // second component (in this, the event not works)
    <hr/>
    <livewire:table-articoli /> // third component

    <!-- fine dell'import dei component livewire (tab: partite, pratiche, articoli) -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <!-- button per l'apertura dei modal -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PagamentoLongModal">Aggiungi pagamento</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Aggiungi assegnatario</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowPagamentiModal">Pagamenti</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ProcedureInesigibilitaModal">Procedure/Inesigibilit&agrave;</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Inizio dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
        <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un pagamento -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="PagamentoLongModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Aggungi un pagamento</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                <div class="basic-form">
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Ente</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Ente" value="" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Partita</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Partita" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno Rif.</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno Riferimento" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Anno</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Anno" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Numero</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Numero" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Carico</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Carico" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Tipologia</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Tipologia">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Imposta</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Imposta">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali imposta" maxlenght="2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mora</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Mora">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Decimali</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Decimali mora" maxlength="2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Pagamento</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Data Registrazione</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Note</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Email" minlength="3" maxlength="255"> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal per l'inserimento di un assegnatario -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Aggiungi un assegnatario</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere l'azione -->
                    <form method="POST" action="#">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Seleziona assegnatari (tieni premuto shift per una selezione multipla):</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control input-rounded" id="sel2">
                                  @if(!empty($users))
                                    @foreach($users as $u)
                                        <option value="{{$u->id}}">{{$u->username}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                  @endif
                                </select>
                              </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Data Assegnazione</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control input-rounded" placeholder="Data Assegn.">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal per visualizzare i pagamenti associati alla partita -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ShowPagamentiModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Pagamenti associati alla partita</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere il corpo del body -->
                    <p>Body da aggiungere, da capire i dati da mostrare a video</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stampa</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal per visualizzare le procedure e le inesigibilita associati alla partita -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ProcedureInesigibilitaModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Procedure e Inesigibilit&agrave;</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- da aggiungere il corpo del body -->
                    <p>Body da aggiungere, da capire i dati da mostrare a video</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger light" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Stampa</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- fine dei modal per gestire le azioni del gestionale -->
 <!--   IMPORTANTE: AGGIUNGERE IL CSRF TOKEN PRIMA DI ANDARE IN PRODUZIONE -->

@endsection
```

For `table-pratiche` i've this structure of my livewire component

- table-pratiche:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Pratiche</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="example4" class="display" style="min-width: 845px">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Soggetto</th>
                                <th>Codice Fiscale</th>
                                <th>Indirizzo</th>
                                <th>Tipo di imposta</th>
                                <th>Carico</th>
                                <th>Riscosso</th>
                                <th>Sgravio</th>
                                <th>Residuo</th>
                                <th>Assegnatario</th>
                                <th>Data assegn.</th>
                                <th>Dettagli</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <livewire:table-pratiche-content />
                        <livewire:tbl-pratiche-footer-filter />
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- table-pratiche-content:

```
<tbody id="filter_result">
    @if (!empty($pratiche))
        <?php
        $carico = 0;
        $riscosso = 0;
        $sgravio = 0;
        $residuo = 0;
        ?>
        @foreach ($pratiche['data'] as $p)
            <tr wire:click="clickPartiteTrigger({{ $p['id_minuta'] }})">
                <td>{{ $p['denominazioneSoggetto'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['codiceFiscale'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['indirizzoPOSTA'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['descrizione_sintetica'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['carico'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['riscosso'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['sgravio'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p['residuo'] }}</td>
                <td>Collaboratore</td>
                <td>{{ $p['data_assegnazione'] }}</td>
                <td><span class="badge light badge-warning">Pending</span></td>
                <?php
                $carico = $carico + $p['carico'];
                $riscosso = $riscosso + $p['riscosso'];
                $sgravio = $sgravio + $p['sgravio'];
                $residuo = $residuo + $p['residuo'];
                ?>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

For `table-partite` in the same way i've:

- table-partite:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title">Partite</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="example5" class="display" style="min-width: 845px">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Anno ruolo</th>
                    <th>Numero ruolo</th>
                    <th>Agente Riscossione</th>
                    <th>Anno imposta</th>
                    <th>Tipo imposta</th>
                    <th>Partita</th>
                    <th>Carico</th>
                    <th>Riscosso</th>
                    <th>Sgravio</th>
                    <th>Residuo</th>
                    <th>Peocedura</th>
                    <th>Inesigibile</th>
                    <th>Stato</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <livewire:table-partite-content />
                <livewire:tbl-partite-footer-filter />
              </table>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- table-partite-content

```
<tbody id="partite_result">
                    @if (!empty($partite))
                    @foreach ($partite['data'] as $pt)
                    <tr wire:click="clickArticoliTrigger({{ $pt['id']}})">
                        <td>{{ $pt['annoRuolo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['numeroRuolo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['agenteRiscossione'] ?? ''}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['annoRif'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['tipoImposta'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['id_minuta_partita'] ?? '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoCarico'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['pagatoNormale'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['pagatoDiscarico'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoResiduo'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['proceduraEsecutiva'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['importoInesigibilita'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pt['stato'] ?? ''}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
</tbody>
```

and in the last, for `table-articoli` i've

- table-articoli

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title">Articoli</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="example4" class="display" style="min-width: 845px">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Codice Tributo</th>
                    <th>Descrizione</th>
                    <th>Progressivo</th>
                    <th>Carico</th>
                    <th>Dettaglio utenza</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <livewire:table-articoli-content />
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-table-articoli-content

```
<tbody id="articoli_result">
    @if (!empty($articoli))
    @foreach ($articoli as $a)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $a->codiceEntrata }}</td>
        <td>{{ $a->descrizioneArticolo }}</td>
        <td>{{ $a->progressivoArticolo}}</td>
        <td>{{ $a->importoCarico }}</td>
        <td>{{ $a->descrizioneArticolo}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

The livewire components are the component posted in the previous question

Comment: @Enzio the tables content (pratiche-content, partite-content and articoli) are inside div container...the whole content?

Comment: @Enzio did you prove using wire:key in the diff <tr> that fires events? something like wire:key="partite-{{ $pt['id'] }}" ???

Comment: @Prospero the tables content yes are inside the div as you see in the code below...i've in example table-pratiche with some <div>, inside this <div> i've the <table> tag and after the <thead> i call the component <livewire:table-pratiche-content>

Comment: I've tried now to use this wire:key="partite-{{ $pt['id'] }}", but for now not works

Comment: Two questions, check if any network event (by inspector browser tool) is emitted when you click there and if in console any error is shown. Do you have any JS code in blades?

Comment: @Prospero, yes using event inspector i've all ok, all works fine and I have no mistakes, but when i click on a row in a table-partite-component nothing happens and nothing happens from the inspector, no errors appear and the click is not really taken.
I don't now how

Comment: Ok, try test with one input element and bind it to a property in partite-content, in the way to see if Livewire is working in that component...I mean after or before the table the input and {{$inputProperty}}, when you write in the input must show that in blade. Can you test it?

Comment: @Prospero, if I got it well, i'm sure that the component partite-content works, this because when i click a row from the component table-pratiche, the table-partite component populates the table rows correctly, but then the click event on the table rows in the table-partite component continues to fail.
In the gestionale.blade.php i've 5 livewire components and events work on the rest (to test events on table-articoli-component i need that works the event on table-partite)

Comment: I don't take for granted Livewire is working just for render blades...if you look at the most issue's post is about some button don't trigger, an input not wrapping from backend, etc. So, in the way to be clearance about that you can prove it testing with another behavior on Livewire responses